# NSBezierPath error with Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, swift2, nsbezierpath

I updated Xcode to the latest version (7.2) and I got the following error:

**Use of undeclared 'NSBezierPath'**

```
extension String {
    ...
}

extension NSBezierPath { //Error here
    ...
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you actually want to create a extension for `UIBezierPath`?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes but its an extension for **NS**BezierPath.

Comment: @Geek20: Is it an OS X project? Do you `import AppKit` ? (But that would be necessary for older Xcode releases as well.)

Comment: As mentioned by @MartinR the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/) state that you need to import `AppKit`.

Comment: I didn't have that error with older Xcode releases.. weird. Now It works with AppKit! Thanks @MartinR  luk2302

Answer (score 0):

`NSBezierPath` is still valid so I guess you didn't:

```
import Cocoa
```

or

```
import AppKit
```

Not h of which rely on the App being OS X oriented.. That way you get `NSBezierPath`

If you're referring to an IOS app (TVOS, WatchKit, or other iOS devices then):

```
import UIKit
```

then you get `UIBezierPath`

There are some minor differences between the two but they pretty much function the same..

Just to edit:

Objective-C and Swift differ a few ways.. (well not really)...

Swift you import Modules (as you can do in Obj-C too - thanks to LLVM / Clang differences so):

`classic objective C`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

`newer objective C`:
    @import Cocoa

The same applies to Swift but you don't import them with '@import'

i.e.

```
import Cocoa
import CoreFoundation
```